# Why can't I read pdf files using python textract?

Tags: python, anaconda, text-extraction

I'm new to python. I'm using `Pycharm 2018.2` and the latest version of `Anaconda`. My operating system is windows 10.

After solving all problems with installing `textract` on windows 10, I got a positive installation result from the `anaconda` prompt. Additionally, I have imported the Project Interpreter from `\continuum\anaconda3\python.exe`.

I want to extract text from large `.pdf` files and save it to `.txt` files.

I have tried using the `test_pdf.py` files from `textract`, but they didn't work.

Here is the end code (own translation from German):

> "textract" is wrong written or can't be found

So I tried my own, following the `textract` page. But it doesn't work either:

Here's my code:

```
import textract
text = textract.process('pfad/large.pdf')
```

Results:

```
    C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/raz/Google Drive/FOM/Master/Master/NurText/Testo.py"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textract-1.6.1-py3.6.egg\textract\parsers\utils.py", line 85, in run
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in init
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/raz/Google Drive/FOM/Master/Master/NurText/Testo.py", line 2, in 
    text = textract.process('pfad/large.pdf')
    File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textract-1.6.1-py3.6.egg\textract\parsers_init_.py", line 77, in process
    return parser.process(filename, encoding, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textract-1.6.1-py3.6.egg\textract\parsers\utils.py", line 46, in process
    byte_string = self.extract(filename, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textract-1.6.1-py3.6.egg\textract\parsers\pdf_parser.py", line 28, in extract
    raise ex
    File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textract-1.6.1-py3.6.egg\textract\parsers\pdf_parser.py", line 20, in extract
    return self.extract_pdftotext(filename, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textract-1.6.1-py3.6.egg\textract\parsers\pdf_parser.py", line 43, in extract_pdftotext
    stdout, _ = self.run(args)
    File "C:\Users\raz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textract-1.6.1-py3.6.egg\textract\parsers\utils.py", line 92, in run
    ' '.join(args), 127, '', '',
    textract.exceptions.ShellError: The command pdftotext pfad/large.pdf - failed with exit code 127
    ------------- stdout -------------
    ------------- stderr -------------
```

Comment: I have the same error. Some hints or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I prefer you to use a virtualBox and install Ubuntu. Its the easiest solution. You can create a shared folder with the virtual system and your windows.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. While I am not able to solve this problem, I looked around the web and discovered that this might be related to the installation of pdftotext package. I am not able to install pdftotext on my Windows 10.

Comment: I have the same problem with pdf using the textract CLI. If I transform the pdf to a png file, textract works. tldr; it's not you, it's textract.

Comment: I have the same issue, How did you solve this issue?